# C system() call parameter expansion

Tags: c, bash

I'm trying to merge a set of files using C `system()` call:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  return system("cat output{1,2} > merged.out");
}
```

The result is:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
cat: output{1,2}: No such file or directory
```

It works if I do it directly in bash:

```
$ ls output{1,2}
output1  output2
$ cat output{1,2}
1,2
3,4
```

How can I enable parameter expansion in the `system()` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that `system` uses `/bin/sh`, which does not expand braces. For instance, try:

```
/bin/sh -c 'echo cat output{1,2}'
```

and compare

```
/bin/bash -c 'echo cat output{1,2}'
```

If you must, something like

```
system("/bin/bash -c 'cat output{1,2} > merged.out'");
```

but why not simply read both files and write the output to `merged.out`?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It's because I currently use `split` to split the input and want to use the same thing for merging output. I know it has some portibility issues, but I'll try to fix that later.

Answer (score 1):

`system` passes the command to `/bin/sh -c`. If parameter expansion does not work as expected `/bin/sh` is not linked to `/bin/bash` on the system. You can explicitely start a bash shell using this:

```
return system("bash -c \"cat output{1,2} > merged.out\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Expansion is a shell duty. Something like `system("/usr/bin/bash -c \"cat output{1,2}\" > merged.out");" should work.

Comment: Thanks. It is `/bin/bash` on my system.